# Find all possible versions of a string whose characters may have multiple variants

Tags: c++, string

I'm looking for some tips on how to find all possible versions of a string whose characters may have multiple variants.

A simple example: 
"Macao" is the starting string. The character 'a' has the variant 'ä', and the character 'o' has the variant 'ö'.

The goal is to obtain the following list from the above information:

```
Macao
Mäcao
Macäo
Mäcäo
Macaö
Mäcaö
Macäö
Mäcäö
```

My approach so far has been to identify and extract the characters with variants to simplify things. The idea is to work on the respective characters rather than the entire word.

```
aao
äao
aäo
ääo
aaö
äaö
aäö
ääö
```

The following code finds the variants that we are working with.

```
std::vector<std::string> variants;
variants.push_back("aä");
variants.push_back("oö");

std::string word = "Macao";
std::vector<std::string> results;
for (auto &variant : variants) {
    for (auto &character : word) {
        if (variant.front() == character) {
            results.push_back(variant);
        }
    }
}

std::cout << "The following characters have variants: ";
for (auto &i : results) {
    std::cout << i.front();
}
std::cout << std::endl;
```

The next step is to find all the possible combinations for the respective characters. To this end, I wrote the following function. It creates a new string out of the first character of each string in `results`.

```
std::string read_results(std::vector<std::string> &results)
{
    std::string s;
    for (auto &c : results) {
        s.push_back(c.front());
    }
    return s;
}
```

The idea is to then change the strings stored in `results` in such a way as to get all the possible combinations, and that's where I'm stuck. I note that `std::rotate` seems like it would be helpful.

Comment: So you're looking for permutations?

Comment: Bear in mind that if you're doing this to help with text comparisons, it's not always sufficient to swap individual characters one for one. For example, in German, ö is likely to be replaced by 'oe'.

Answer (score 0):

An inverted index may be useful.

You can store all the letters that have multiple variants in a vector, in order, and a vector with a grouping index for each letter, so that the i-th letter belongs to the group `I[i]`, and all the letters whose index is the same than `I[i]` are variants from the same letter:

```cpp
string L = "aoäöâô"; // disclaimer: i don't know if this is really in order
unsigned int I[]  = {0,1,0,1,0,1};
// this means that "aäâ" belong to group 0, and "oöô" belong to group 1
```

You can build the inverted index for the previous `L` and `I` with something like this:

```cpp
vector<vector<unsigned int> > groups;
// groups[k] stores the indices in L of the letters that belongs to the k-th group.
// do groups.reserve to make this operation more efficient
for(size_t i = 0; i < L.size(); ++i)
{
  unsigned int idx = I[i];
  if(idx <= groups.size()) groups.resize(idx+1);
  groups[idx].push_back(i);
}
```

It is important that letters in `L` are in order, so you can do a binary search on it later, that takes `O(logn)` instead of `O(n)` of a usual loop. Then, once you have the group of your letter, you can find its variants with an inverted index:

```cpp
char letter = 'a';
string::iterator it = std::lower_bound(L.begin(), L.end(), letter);
if(it != L.end() && *it == letter)
{
  unsigned int idx = I[ it - L.begin() ];
  // the letter has variants because it belongs to group idx
  const vector<unsigned int>& group = groups[idx];
  for(vector<unsigned int>::const_iterator git = group.begin();
    git != group.end(); ++git)
  {
    // now, L[*git] is one of the variants of letter
    ...
  }
}
```